# What am I doing wrong with DateTime.strptime?

Tags: ruby, datetime

My ruby program says that my date is invalid when I do that:

```
format = "%D/%M/%Y %H:%M:%S:3N"
date = "21/03/2011 16:39:11.642"

DateTime.strptime(time, format)
```

I have also tried this one:

```
format = "%D/%M/%Y %H:%M:%S:3"
```

All I get is this:

```
ArgumentError: invalid date    
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1688:in `new_by_frags'    
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:1713:in `strptime'
        from (irb):12  
        from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like you were getting strptime's format directives confused. Notice how `%M` is in `format` twice, once representing the month and the next time representing the minute?

`%D` means the date as `%m / %d / %y`.

`%d` means the day of the month [01,31]

`%M` means the minute [00,59]

`%m` means the month number [01,12]

This should work:

```
format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
date_time = "21/03/2011 16:39:11.642"

puts DateTime.strptime(date_time, format) #=> 2011-03-21T16:39:11+00:00
```

Here's a [strptime reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html)

Comment: So the format string symbols for `strftime` and `strptime` have different meanings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`datetime.to_date.strftime(format)`

or

`datetime.to_time`