# RoR: Parse datetime UTC string into timezone specific

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, datetime, timezone

Datetimes are being stored in MySQL as UTC.

In my app I've set: config.time_zone = 'UTC'

In my application_controller I set the users selected timezone:

```
around_filter :user_time_zone, :if => :current_user

def user_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone, &block)
end
```

I can confirm this works by `<%= Time.zone.now%>` as it returns the user's set timezone

I then do a select query to grab the datetime field, and present it to the user as part of an array.

In my view, I have:

```
<%= Time.zone.parse(item[1]).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") %>
```

which just outputs the datetime as-is (UTC), not in the user's specific time zone.

What do I need to change in order for the date and time to display correctly in the user's desired timezone?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Edit:

Per Benjamin's suggestions, I had to modify it slightly to get it to work (was getting the same error) - `Time.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').in_time_zone(Time.zone)` but 2 issues still remain.

1 - the original datetime is: 2013-07-25 22:27:50, but what is displayed is: 2013-07-25 16:27:50 -1000 my user timezone is Hawaii at -10 from UTC, but this only shows a 6 hr difference?

2 - How do I get this in a format that is easily readable by users (07/25/2013 12:27 PM)? Thanks again

Solved: 
Thanks to Benjamin.  I forgot to mention that I'm (stuck) using 1.8.7, so I had to work through a few minor differences between 1.8.7 and 1.9.3, but got it working with:

```
<%= DateTime.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').in_time_zone(Time.zone).to_formatted_s(:long)%>
```

Updated:  Got it into the format I wanted (06/20/2013 01:00 AM) using:

```
DateTime.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M ').in_time_zone(Time.zone).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Comment: can you please look into this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: I've read through that, and while I see parse(), it still doesn't convert my time from UTC to the required timezone, nor do I want to see the UTC time displayed with an offset (ie. 2013-7-26 10:00 HST -10).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Time.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').in_time_zone(Time.zone)
```

Answer to the bonus questions

1. Check the time zone of your db server and double check your rails data (default config / user TZ)
2. use `to_formatted_s` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s

Comment: I get the following error: ActionView::Template::Error (invalid strptime format - `%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'):  I found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380838/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-datetime-strptime), and tried changing the %I to %H, but get the same error.

Comment: My bad, I copy pasted that string from your question, but it should be the format of the string from the database. Edited my answer with the correct format, please try again

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify it slightly to get it to work (was getting the same error) - Time.strptime(item[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').in_time_zone(Time.zone) but 2 issues still remain.  1 - the original datetime is: 2013-07-25 22:27:50, but what is displayed is: 2013-07-25 16:27:50 -1000 my user timezone is Hawaii at -10 from UTC, but this only shows a 6 hr difference?  2 - How do I get this in a format that is easily readable by users (07/25/2013 12:27 PM)? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working (see above), but still can't get the format the way I like.  I'm using 1.8.7 and it does not like: %m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p for some reason.  Any thoughts on how to get it to this format? Thanks again.

Comment: Ignore my last question, got it fixed.  Thanks again for your assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, kind of busy. Glad you fixed it